# how can i delay the angular ui tour step?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour.
how can i display the tour step popup after some time. 
angular ui tour library options has been removed.please find below.
Breaking changes in 0.8.0:
The following tour step options have been removed: popupDelay, popupCloseDelay, animation

Is there any way to delay the angualr ui tour step.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
1. call a function on "tour-step-on-next" of previous step popup.

2. Inside that function add this below code to delay the next popup

$timeout(function(d){
                    var tour = uiTourService.getTourByName('oneTour');
                        tour.goTo('mfgGroups');
                        $scope.$apply();
                },100);
```